# Creating grid from spatio temporal point data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, r, vector-grid

I have a spatio-temporal point data of species sighting with monthly observation for random locations within my study area. I wish to create a grid(fishnet) for each month for each year. Also, certain grids for a month and year has multiple points so need to derive mean.

Old [I have point data for an area over a period of years (2010-2014). I would like to create a grid of 0.25 X 0.25 decimal degrees for each month. Also to derive a mean where there are more than one point in a grid mesh for that particular month. Purpose of creating this grid is to extract the values from rasters based on the grid.]

Comment: What have you tried?  Where precisely are you stuck?  You have tags for R and ArcGIS for Desktop and Python, but what are you using to try and do this?

Comment: i have daily point locations of species siting for a large area over period of few years. I wish to convert them to a monthwise grid/fishnet. Problem i face is when we do spatial join it takes mean of all points within the grid regardless of their month and year.

Comment: There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to improve it with these clarifications.

Comment: I agree, I'm not fully understanding the question but it seems like the solution will somehow involve a polygon [Fishnet](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-fishnet.htm), then [Tabulate Intersection](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/tabulate-intersection.htm), if you have an Advanced license. You can specify your "Month" field in the _Class Fields_ parameter to get a breakdown by month.

Comment: This is a good question. Do you need to do it in R or ArcGIS Desktop? and share a tiny subset of your data in your question?

Comment: To me it looks like there has been little to no improvement in your question after the last edit.  What have you tried and where are you stuck?